# How to copy the contents of an FTP directory to a shared network path?

Tags: ssis, ftp, business-intelligence

I have the need to copy the entire contents of a directory on a FTP location onto a shared networked location. FTP Task has you specify the exact file name (not a directory) and File System Task does not allow accessing a FTP location.

**EDIT**: I ended up writing a script task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had some similar issues with the FTP task before. In my case, the file names changed based on the date and some other criteria. I ended up using a Script Task to perform the FTP operation.

It looks like this is what you ended up doing as well. I'd be curious if anyone else can come up with a better way to use the FTP task. It's nice to have...but VERY limited.

Answer (score 4):

Nothing like reviving a really old thread... but there is a solution to this.

To copy the all files from a directory then specify your remote path to be /[directory name]/*

Or for just files and not directories /[directory name]/*.*

Or specific file types;  /[directory name]/*.csv

Answer (score 1):

When I need to do this sort of thing I use a batch file to call FTP on the command line and use the mget command. Then I call the batch from the DTS/DTSX package.