# SSIS download everything from FTP

Tags: ssis, ftp

I want to ***every week automaticly*** download all data on FTP server with **SSIS** **FTP task**.

**(=Copy of whole ftp server to our local server.)**

Problem is that on FTP there is many folders and the structure is changing.

For exmple:

I want to download all files from /folder

so I know that i can use `/folder/*.*`

but sometimes happen that somebody add new folder  - `/folder/subfolder/`

so how to specify the FTP task to download all data from FTP even in subfloders or in realy deep structure like:

```
folder/subforlder/subfolder/.....
```

Thanks,
Martin

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to copy the contents of an FTP directory to a shared network path?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42171/how-to-copy-the-contents-of-an-ftp-directory-to-a-shared-network-path)

Comment: Specifically, see [the answer by @Carl](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2118425/850848).

Comment: Hello @MartinPrikryl, thank you for your reply but i want to download with one FTP task many folders with its content as I mentioned I want to donwload everyting even subfolders. I tried /folder/* but it does not work for folders with underscore (/folder/_subfolder) EDIT: I tried /folder/* and /folder/*.* in both cases it download files only in /folder but not in subfolders